# SwiftUI: change map type on map view?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am adding a map view like this:

```
            Map(coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion)
                                .frame(height: 400, alignment: .center)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .shadow(radius: 4)
```

Map shows up as this:

[image]

I want to allow the user to change the map type (satellite, etc...).

Is there a way to set the map type in SwiftUI?

Comment: You need to use a 'UIKit MapView' in a 'UIViewRepresentable'. Nothing was updated with Maps this year, sadly.

Comment: Yah, I just read a bunch of stuff online and I thought that had to be the case... Even something as simple as dropping a pin is a mess due to lack of proper gesture location support in SwiftUI... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for now I fear that you have to access the mapType using

`MKMapView.appearance().mapType = .satellite` // or any other map type

You can use it just onAppear.
I am not sure if there is a better way, but at least it works :)

For more detailed specifications the UIKit Mapview is needed for now.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Works fine with me.

Comment: @Bortol15 This solution does not work.

Answer (score -2):

```
.onAppear {
  MKMapView.appearance().mapType = .satellite
}
```

Comment: This is a thanks and a restating of Bortol15's answer?